Movie I watched in 2013 with crazy mother and abused children
I need help with naming a movie that I watched in 2013 on Netflix. It was about a family, the mother was crazy, the dad left her and their kids who were teenagers. The mother let her father pay her to have sex with her girls. The one daughter ended up dying from a beating I think?
The kids tried to reach out to the pastor or someone? Who happened to be an alcoholic; the mother ended up intercepting the note the kids wrote to the pastor, she ended up getting him drunk and sleeping with him. I think the mom was also an alcoholic. Maybe she killed the dad when he tried leaving her? In the end I think maybe one daughter lived? But the boy shot his mom maybe himself?
I don't think it was horror per say, but it was very suspenseful and dramatic. I believe it was American as well. Any ideas?

I think I know what you're after. Was it a horror movie? Was it American?

I don't think it was horror per say, but it was very suspenseful and dramatic. I believe it was american as well.

Thanks. Added & posted a possible match (that's so horrific it might as well be horror...)

YESSSS!!! That's it! Thank you!

This sounds a lot like The Afflicted from 2010 (or 2012 in the US), though some details are a bit off.

A story of incomprehensible abuse delivered by an explosively violent mother of four. Journey through the mind of a child that experiences a living hell, defined and defended by the twisted religious beliefs of her mother.

The mother is insane and alcoholic and abuses her children (3 daughters and a boy). When the dad tries to leave, the mom kills him. One daughter is prostituted and another is beaten to death. And they try to reach out to a local TV pastor, but to no avail. Sadly, the movie was based on real-life events. Here's the trailer:



